# Convert element with attribute to new elements with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

How do you convert an element with a specific attribute to a new parent element with children in xslt?
More specifically, every time there is an element with the "WeightUOM" or "VolumeUOM" attribute, a new element should be created.

The desire is to convert the following elements with attributes:

```
  <anyWeightElementName WeightUOM="LBS">123.45</anyWeightElementName>
  <anyVolumeElementName VolumeUOM="CUF">0.65</anyVolumeElementName>
```

to this, a parent element (with no value), a new "Weight" or "Volume" element and a new "WeightUOM" or "VolumeUOM" element with the value of the attribute.

```
        <anyWeightElementName >
            <Weight>123.45</Weight>
            <WeightUOM>LBS</WeightUOM>
        </anyWeightElementName >
        <anyVolumeElementName>
            <Volume>0.65</Volume>
            <VolumeUOM>CUF</VolumeUOM>
        </anyVolumeElementName>
```

**input XML**

```
<Response>
<Deliveries>
    <Delivery>
        <EstimatedWeight WeightUOM="LBS">123.45</EstimatedWeight>
        <EstimatedVolume VolumeUOM="CUF">0.65</EstimatedVolume>
        <Customers>
            <Customer>
                <Name>Smith</Name>
                <Zip>12345</Zip>
                <ActualWeight WeightUOM="TON">1.00</ActualWeight>
                <ActualVolume VolumeUOM="CUI">400.00</ActualVolume>
            </Customer>
            <Customer>
                <Name>Jones</Name>
                <Zip>54321</Zip>
                <ActualWeight WeightUOM="TON">0.024</ActualWeight>
                <ActualVolume VolumeUOM="CUF">0.45</ActualVolume>
            </Customer>
        </Customers>
    </Delivery>
</Deliveries>
</Response>
```

**Desired output**

```
<Response>
<Deliveries>
    <Delivery>
        <EstimatedWeight>
            <Weight>123.45</Weight>
            <WeightUOM>LBS</WeightUOM>
        </EstimatedWeight>
        <EstimatedVolume>
            <Volume>0.65</Volume>
            <VolumeUOM>CUF</VolumeUOM>
        </EstimatedVolume>
        <Customers>
            <Customer>
                <Name>Smith</Name>
                <Zip>12345</Zip>
                <ActualWeight>
                    <Weight>1.00</Weight>
                    <WeightUOM>TON</WeightUOM>
                </ActualWeight>
                <ActualVolume>
                    <Volume>400.00</Volume>
                    <VolumeUOM>CUI</VolumeUOM>
                </ActualVolume>
            </Customer>
            <Customer>
                <Name>Jones</Name>
                <Zip>54321</Zip>
                <ActualWeight>
                    <Weight>0.024</Weight>
                    <WeightUOM>TON</WeightUOM>
                </ActualWeight>
                <ActualVolume>
                    <Volume>0.45</Volume>
                    <VolumeUOM>CUF</VolumeUOM>
                </ActualVolume>
            </Customer>
        </Customers>
    <Delivery>
</Deliveries>
</Response>
```

**attempted XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@WeightUOM">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:element name="Weight">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="WeightUOM">
            <xsl:value-of select="@WeightUOM"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@VolumeUOM">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
        <xsl:element name="Volume">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="VolumeUOM">
            <xsl:value-of select="@VolumeUOM"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the current output from the listed xslt.  The xslt is not making new elements.

```
<Response>
<Deliveries>
    <Delivery>
        <EstimatedWeight>123.45</EstimatedWeight>
        <EstimatedVolume>0.65</EstimatedVolume>
        <Customers>
            <Customer>
                <Name>Smith</Name>
                <Zip>12345</Zip>
                <ActualWeight>1.00</ActualWeight>
                <ActualVolume>400.00</ActualVolume>
            </Customer>
            <Customer>
                <Name>Jones</Name>
                <Zip>54321</Zip>
                <ActualWeight>0.024</ActualWeight>
                <ActualVolume>0.45</ActualVolume>
            </Customer>
        </Customers>
    </Delivery>
</Deliveries>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your use of `<xsl:apply-templates/>`; this is short for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />`, so it selects nodes, but not attributes. Without any attributes of an element being selected, your templates for them will simply never match.

Instead you need to do this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
```

In fact, you probably want to use the "identity template" here anyway

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, in the template matching `@WeightUOM` you currently do `<xsl:value-of select="@WeightUOM"/>`, but as you are already matching the `@WeightUOM` then this will return nothing, as it will be trying to select an attribute of the current attribute. You need to do this to get the value of the current attribute

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

And do this to get the value of the parent element

```
<xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
```

You also don't need to do `<xsl:element name="{name(.)}">` because the template matching `*` will create the containing element. (And `name(.)` gets the name of the attribute. You probably should have done `name(..)` here anyway).

Finally, you probably need templates explicitly matching the child text nodes, to prevent them getting output twice

```
<xsl:template match="*[@WeightUOM]/text()" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@WeightUOM]/text()" />
<xsl:template match="*[@VolumeUOM]/text()" />

<xsl:template match="@WeightUOM">
    <Weight>
        <xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
    </Weight>
    <WeightUOM>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </WeightUOM>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@VolumeUOM">
    <Volume>
        <xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
    </Volume>
    <VolumeUOM>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </VolumeUOM>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note there is no need to use `xsl:element` if the name of the element is static.

Or combine the templates, if you like...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@WeightUOM|@VolumeUOM]/text()" />

<xsl:template match="@WeightUOM|@VolumeUOM">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(name(), 'UOM')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="../text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I see what you mean by the Identity template. There is just one issue with the output. The <Weight> tag has the attribute value and needs the original weight value.  Here is an example:    <EstimatedWeight>
        <Weight>LBS</Weight>
        <WeightUOM>LBS</WeightUOM>
      </EstimatedWeight>
instead of   <EstimatedWeight>
        <Weight>123.45</Weight>
        <WeightUOM>LBS</WeightUOM>
      </EstimatedWeight>

Comment: My apologies. I have made a correction to my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.